# session login keep refreshing page

Tags: php, html, session

I'm doing a login system for my webpage, when i key in the correct login id and password the page refresh back to the login page. I did all the things correct but the session keep messing things up and I don't know where is the error.

- index.php

  ```
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
  header("location:login.php");
  }
  ```
- server.php

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)){
      array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }

  if (empty($password)){
      array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }
  if(count($errors) == 0){
      $password = md5($password);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM register where username='$username' AND password = '$password'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){//user found      
  $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  if ($logged_in_user['type'] == 'admin') {

          $_SESSION['loggedin']  = true;
          $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
          $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
          header('location: admin.php');  
  }
  else{
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
      $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
      header('location: index.php');
  }

  }

  }
  }
  ```

Comment: did you var_dump($_SESSION) before the redirect in the index to check if the session index exists?

Comment: Are you logging in as an administrator? Have you tried logging out `$_SESSION` and `$logged_in_user`? Also, how are you referencing `server.php` and its respective code? It sounds like you're probably invoking that functionality on the very page you're being redirected to.

Comment: `$password = md5($password);` why. or rather why bother.

Comment: call `session_start();` at the top of `server.php`

Comment: Another obvious question that perhaps just got overlooked; have you tried in multiple browsers? Might just be a cookie issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both pages should have `session_start()` at the top of code

for example
index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

server.php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

and so on

Another thing offtopic. Prefer using PDO instead of mysqli_ for database access

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php